# Compare array elements,remove the one with the lowest score

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

There are 200 documents in school db. I must remove each document which has "type":"homework" and the lowest score.

```
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "aimee Zank",
        "scores" :
        [
            {
                "type" : "exam",
                "score" : 1.463179736705023
            },
            {
                "type" : "quiz",
                "score" : 11.78273309957772
            },
            {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 6.676176060654615
            },
            {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 35.8740349954354
            }
        ]
    }
```

For example,here

```
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 6.676176060654615
    }
```

must be removed  as score = 6.6 < 35.8

I sorted all the documents like this:

```
db.students.find({"scores.type":"homework"}).sort({"scores.score":1})
```

But I do not know how then to remove the doc having the lowest score and type:homework??? 
 NOTE: how to solve it by not using aggregation method? E.g., by sorting and then updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a couple of steps. The first step is to grab a list of the documents with the minimum score by using the aggregation framework with [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match), [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operators that streamlines your documents to find the minimum score for each document:

```
lowest_scores_docs = db.school.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": {"scores.type": "homework"} },
    { "$unwind": "$scores" },  { "$match": {"scores.type": "homework"} },
    { "$group": { "_id":"$_id", "lowest_score": {"$min": "$scores.score" } } } ] )
```

The second step is to loop through the dictionary above and use the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator in the update query to remove the element from the array as follows:

```
for result in lowest_scores_docs["result"]:
    db.school.update({ "_id": result["_id"] }, 
        { "$pull": { "scores": { "score": result["lowest_score"] } } } )
```

Comment: Hi, Chridam. I'm grateful to you a lot for your quick reply. But unfortunately,it also did not remove the element of array having "type":"homework" and the lowest value in each _id., in each document.

Comment: @sapio_l Any error messages being displayed? Have you tried printing the object `lowest_scores_docs` to see if anything is being returned from the aggregation?

Comment: Yes,I did. The loop does not work,it prints nothing. @chridam

Comment: Now I use another method: db.students.find({"scores.type":"homework"}).sort({"scores.score":1})
But I do not know how to remove the second document having the lowest score and type:homework using update function.  @chridam

Comment: I againly tried your code. Thanks a lot! It worked. But it deletes the min score in scores array, however, I would like to delete an item having minimum score among  "type":"homework". Although you've written { "$match": {"scores.type": "homework"} }, I see it does not take it consider.Why? I've trouble in fix it.

Comment: @sapio_l You are correct, you would need to do another `$match` operation after the `$unwind`. I have thus edited my answer to reflect this change. If this answer was helpful, please consider marking/accepting it for the benefit of other users although there is no obligation for you to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot,chridam! I also tried to use $match operator,but in wrong place. By the way, do you know how to solve it by sorting and then updating method? I mean not using aggregation method.

Comment: i tweaked your loop, as the the iteration you wrote didnt work for me:
   

lowest_scores_docs.forEach(function(i, v){ db.school.update({ "_id": i._id }, { "$pull": { "scores": { "score": i.lowest_score } } } ) });

Comment: @kennydust Thanks for your feedback, was the loop you wrote in Python?

Comment: javascript via mongoshell

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymongo
import sys

# connnecto to the db on standard port
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

db = connection.school           # attach to db
students = db.students        # specify the colllection


try:

        cursor = students.find({})
        print(type(cursor))
        for doc in cursor:
            hw_scores = []
            for item in doc["scores"]:
                if item["type"] == "homework":
                    hw_scores.append(item["score"])
            hw_scores.sort()
            hw_min = hw_scores[0]
            #students.update({"_id": doc["_id"]},
             #           {"$pull":{"scores":{"score":hw_min}}})


except:
    print ("Error trying to read collection:" + sys.exc_info()[0])
```