# Reach to array subdocument in mongodb

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

How to reach to the last element of scores array with score value: 64.8 ??? 
I try to use $pull operator,but I have 200 documents like this form. So, I can't make use of exact value of latest element of scores array.

```
{
"_id" : 198,
"name" : "Timothy Harrod",
"scores" : [
    {
        "type" : "exam",
        "score" : 11.9075674046519
    },
    {
        "type" : "quiz",
        "score" : 20.51879961777022
    },
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 55.85952928204192
    },
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 64.85650354990375
    }       ]
}
```

Comment: What you mean by  *last element of scores array*?

Comment: @Kasra in the homework assignment OP should remove the subdocument where score is the lowest in the array for each document.

Comment: In more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439688/compare-array-elements-remove-the-one-with-the-lowest-score @Kasra

Comment: This might be helpful to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335009/mongodb-find-the-minimum-element-in-array-and-delete-it

Comment: @Vishwas This link is great! Thanks a lot! But it removes the min score and does not consider "type":"homework", although it is written {$match: {scores.type: "homework"}. I try to fix it,but it gives an error such as using aggregation function in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to put that document into a python dict if it's in string format:

```
import json
doc_json = json.loads(doc_string)
```

Then to access the LAST element of the scores array, just do:

```
last_element = doc_json['scores'][-1]
```

The ['scores'] tells us to get the 'scores' array from our json_doc, and the [-1] tells us to access the last element of this 'scores' array. From there, if you wanted the score from the last_element, you would just do:

```
last_score = last_element['score']
```

You could have also gotten it straight by doing:

```
last_score = doc_json['scores'][-1]['score']
```

Comment: It gave "TypeError: expected string or buffer". Anyway,thanks for your quick reply, @ Parminder Shergill. You can get detailed inf about the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439688/compare-array-elements-remove-the-one-with-the-lowest-score